# Mentions, createdAt field

Tags: discord.js

I cannot fix the error for mentioning third-party users, errors start on 'Roles' and the server login date, the date the account was created.

Please Help.

```
    ... [cut]

    } else if (command === 'user') {
    let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(`Akirabot. Find of user.`)
        .setColor(0x348fcd)
        .setTitle('')
        .addField(`Username`,`${user.username}`, true)
        .addField(`User id`,`${user.id}`, true)
        .addField(`Status`,`${user.presence.status}`, true)
        .addField(`Date of create account`, `${moment(user.createdAt).toString().substr(0, 15)}\n(${moment(user.createdAt).fromNow()})`, true)
        .addField("Currently Playing", user.presence.game || "Nothing.", true)
        .addField(`Join date to server`, `${moment(user.joinedAt).toString().substr(0, 15)}\n(${moment(user.joinedAt).fromNow()})`, true)
        .addField('Roles', `${user.members.roles}.`, true)
        .setFooter(`— Akirabot, made with love by setosh, 2019.`)
        .setTimestamp('')
        .setThumbnail(`${user.displayAvatarURL}`)
        message.channel.send({ embed });
```

I get this error message

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined
```

Comment: `let guildmember = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0] ) || message.author)` it will get the info about the user from the guild ou using it just change from to guildmember thing that you need to get from the guild for example: roles, createdAt,joinedAt,etc

Comment: Split code and error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`User` class](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) (which is what both `message.mentions.users.first()` and `message.author` return) doesn't have a `members` property, so you're trying to access something that doesn't exist.

If you want to find out a person's roles you'll have to get a [`GuildMember` representation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles) of that person. One way of doing that is like this:

```
const guildMember = message.guild.members.find(val => val.id === user.id);
```

Then you can do `guildMember.roles` and use that however you like.

---

Example:

```
let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
const guildMember = message.guild.members.find(val => val.id === user.id);
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  // Do whatever you want with the roles:
  .addField('Roles', `${guildMember.roles}.`, true)
```

Comment: Give an example code, what will it look like? Take an example of my code, pls.

Comment: It's fairly straightfoward, just declare it and use it. Added an example to the answer.